# Error: The following dependencies are imported but could not be resolved. Unable to use custom library we created using vue and vite

Tags: vue.js, shared-libraries, vite

Have created library that contain component, enums and interfaces using vite and vue.

Have installed the library using npm install file:./dist/

Library appeared in nodemodule folder.

After importing specific component it throw below exception

Error: The following dependencies are imported but could not be resolved:

test-component (imported by D:/Workspace/SulekhaAppFrameWork/Sul_App_Base_V1/ViteCustomLibary/src/App.vue?id=0)

Are they installed?
at file:../node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-df561101.js:45705:23    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async file:///.../node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-df561101.js:45114:38

Have created common library using vue and vite.

npm run build will create the library in dist folder

Have mention that dist folder in package.json ("privatelibrary":file/../dist) to install the custom library.

After executing npm install

Able to find  the folder in the name of privatelibrary.

imported component from privatelibrary

Getting below error when we run the application using npm run dev

Error: The following dependencies are imported but could not be resolved:

test-component (imported by D:/Workspace/SulekhaAppFrameWork/Sul_App_Base_V1/ViteCustomLibary/src/App.vue?id=0)

Are they installed?
at file:../node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-df561101.js:45705:23    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async file:///.../node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-df561101.js:45114:38

Answer (score -1):

You should use the following as a workaround:

`import type { types } from 'xxx'`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).